# Error "Cannot find name CONTEXT" React Router 6 and useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context, use-context

I can't find a way to pass my data to all the children with React Router 6 and useContext hook. When I wrap the `<Routes></Routes>` with my Context.Provider and call it with the Context.Consumer inside my component an error appears:

**The error: Cannot find name 'ShopContext'.**

1.The App.tsx with the Routes and the Context.Provider

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../../pages/Home';
import SharedLayout from '../../layouts/SharedLayout';
import Artists from '../../pages/Artists';
import Contact from '../../pages/Contact';
import NotFound from '../../pages/NotFound';
import { Shop } from '../../interfaces/Shop';
import Data from '../../data.json';


function App() {

    const [Infos] = useState<Shop>(Data)
    const ShopContext = createContext({})

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ShopContext.Provider value={Infos}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<SharedLayout />}>
                        <Route index element={<Home />} />
                        <Route path='artists' element={<Artists />}/>
                        <Route path='contact' element={<Contact />}/>
                        <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </ShopContext.Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )}

export default App;
```

And the children component :

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

function Artists(){

    const shop = useContext(ShopContext)

    return <>
        Artists
    </>
}

export default Artists;
```

I tried:

1. Wrapping the 1st Route containing the SharedLayout ==> Doesn't work, the Routes have to be direct children of `<Routes>`
2. Wrapping every component inside every Route like this :

   ```
    <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={
                    <ShopContext.Provider value={Infos}>
                    <SharedLayout />
                    </ShopContext.Provider>
                }>
                    <Route index element={
                        <ShopContext.Provider value={Infos}>
                            <Home />
                        </ShopContext.Provider>
                    } />
                    <Route path='artists' element={
                        <ShopContext.Provider value={Infos}>
                            <Artists />
                        </ShopContext.Provider>
                    }/>
                    <Route path='contact' element={

                        <ShopContext.Provider value={Infos}>
                            <Contact />
                        </ShopContext.Provider>
                    }/>
                    <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
   ```

   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `ShopContext` React Context should be declared ***outside*** any React component. By declaring it inside `App` you are creating a new context every time `App` renders. Because `ShopContext` is declared inside `App` it isn't defined to use with the `useContext` hook in the routed components trying to consume the context value.

## Solution

Move `ShopContext` into it's own file so it can be created and exported/imported for consumption.

Example:

ShopContext

```
import React, { useContext, useState, createContext } from 'react';

const ShopContext = createContext({});

const ShopProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [infos, setInfos] = useState<Shop>(Data);

  ... business logic to set/update infos state, etc ...

  return (
    <ShopContext.Provider value={infos}>
      {children}
    </ShopContext.Provider>
  );
};

export useShopContext = () => useContext(ShopContext);

export default ShopProvider;
```

App

```
import ShopProvider from '../path/to/ShopProvider';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ShopProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<SharedLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='artists' element={<Artists />}/>
            <Route path='contact' element={<Contact />}/>
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </ShopProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Artists

```
import { useShopContext } from '../path/to/ShopProvider';

function Artists(){
  const shop = useShopContext();

  return (
    <>
      Artists
    </>
  );
}
```